# check if string contains exactly one char

Tags: c#, string, contains

How could I check if a string contains exactly one char?

Example:

- `strings` → check for 1 `i` → `true`
- `strings` → check for 1 `s` → `false`

I've tried to use `Contains` but it checks for 1 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this Linq query to solve it.

```
"strings".Where(c => c == 's').Count() == 1 // gives false
"strings".Where(c => c == 'i').Count() == 1 // gives true
```

Explanaition:

- The `Where` method ask for a lamdba expression that checks if a char (variable `c`) of the given string (`strings`) is equal to respectively `s` or `i` and returns a list of chars that are equal to the condition.
- The `Count` method counts the results of that list.
- Finaly just check if the result is equal to one.

Comment: You can shorten with `"strings".Count(c => c == 's') == 1`

Comment: This may do far more work than required if the string is millions of characters long and contains lots of repeats of the character. I'd usually advocate *against* counting if you don't actually want to know the count. Here, you don't need the count, you just need to classify the string by 0, 1 or *more than 1*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: in that case he could use `bool moreThan1 = "strings".Where(c => c == 's').Skip(1).Any()`

Comment: You could also do it the wrong way: Put in a try-catch "strings".Single(condition) and act whenever the catch is run or not.

Comment: @bradbury9: Yeah it's totaly wrong. If that was an answer -1 from me ;).